# How to get rid off Password expiry error message when connecting to Oracle/DB2 Database in solaris shell script/perl program?

Tags: perl, shell, oracle11g, solaris, ora-28002

I am connecting to **Oracle/DB2** databases through **shell script/ Perl program**. Databases that i am connecting will need **password change every 60 days**. This is according to our security policy and cannot be changed. But this is **creating problem when connecting to Databases** through shell script or perl program. To connect to oracle DB we use below through shell script:

```
sqlplus -s ${USER_NAME}/${PASSWD}@${DATABASE_NAME} <<EOF > $SQL_LOG/SITE_SQL.log
set echo off
set trimspool on
set pages 0
set linesize 1500
set feedback off
set head off

spool ${ETL_DIR}/SITE.txt
select LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN1))||'|'||LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN2)) from TABLE where COLUMN2 IN      (${SITES});
exit
EOF

grep -i 'error' $SQL_LOG/SITE_SQL.log
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo "\n\n---------------------------->>`date`extraction successful\n\n---------------------------->>"  >> $log
else
echo "\n\n---------------------------->>`date` Error with  extraction from Table\n\n---------------------------->>" >> $log
exit -5
fi
```

But SITE_SQL.log which holds the log for database connectivity part is getting below error message in it.

```
ERROR:
ORA-28002: the password will expire within 13 days
```

which is making scripts to fail. but connecting happens to Database and we get required data in spool file. When script checks for error in log file SITE_SQL.log its failing. I dont want to change the error handling part but to suppress this message to be displayed/logged into logfile, so that script will not see this error message in logfile.

Also we have got a perl script which is facing same problem.Below is the code used.

```
my $l_Var_SQL_Statement="Select to_date('$Var_Data_Date_1','YYYY-MM-DD')-max(load_date)     from TABLE where LOAD_STATUS='Success'";

   $RetVal=SubExecuteSQL($Var_REP_TMP,$Var_USER_DB,$Var_USER_DBUSER,$Var_USER_DBPASSWORD,$l_Var_SQL_Statement);
if($RetVal eq "ERROR") {
    $system_date=`date`;
    chomp($system_date);
    $Message="$system_date:Error Executing Query   :$l_Var_SQL_Statement\n$system_date:Database Details:DB=$Var_USER_DB,Use
    r ID=$Var_USER_DBUSER, Password= $Var_USER_DBPASSWORD  for $my_filename Repository";
    SubWriteLogMsg("$Var_REP_LOG","$Var_REP_LOGFILE","$Message");
    $Message="Error Executing Query :$l_Var_SQL_Statement. Check log file for        connection details.";
    SubWriteMailMsg("$Var_INFA_MAILFOLDER","$Var_INFA_MAILFILE","$Message");
           SubLogLoadAbort("$Var_REP_LOG","$Var_REP_LOGFILE","$Var_INFA_MAILFOLDER","$Var_INFA_MAILFILE");
    exit -1;
    }
```

Here since we are getting the password expiry alert error message SubExecuteSQL function is returning "ERROR" as return value which is making perl script to fail.

DBA's are not agreeing to set password does not expire option as its against security policy. Password is set to change every 60 days. so this error message will start popuping up and causing failure.

Please let me know how can i suppress this error message from getting/ logging into logfile.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before your redirection to the log file, put a grep command in a pipe such as:

`| grep -v '^\s*\(ERROR:$\|ORA-\)'`

ie:

```
sqlplus -s ${USER_NAME}/${PASSWD}@${DATABASE_NAME} <<EOF | grep -v '^\s*\(ERROR:|ORA-)' > $SQL_LOG/SITE_SQL.log
```

Verify first that it works with a sample file: not all versions of `grep` support `\s`. If yours does not, use `[ \t]` instead (yes, the space character must be there, it's not a typo).

Comment: But i have somethin like this **Batch_val=`sqlplus -s $User/$Pwd@$server <<EOF
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
set verify off
set heading off
set echo off

select max(num) from table where dt in( select max(dt) from table2 where dt < trunc(sysdate));
EOF`
echo $Batch_val**. So $Batch_val is evaluating to _**ORA-28002: the password will expire within 6 days 23339630**_. I have many different situations like this and dont want to keep changing logic for each scenario but would rather like to suppress error message ORA-28002: the password will expire within 6 days itself. Pls help in this regard

Comment: Above solution given by you is not working. I see the error message being grepped.